# jQuery - Remove class from any <li> that wasn't just clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, removeclass, toggleclass

Lets say I have list like this...

```
<ul>
  <li class="one">One</li>
  <li class="two">Two</li>
  <li class="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

...and I want to be able to toggle class in the li's...

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    $( "li" ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

..also I want the li's except the one that was clicked to never show as '.active' while still maintaining the toggleClass ability in the '.active' li

So I was thinking maybe I want to removeClass from any other li's except the one what was clicked. I don't know how I could do that though...

Any ideas on how to achieve something like that? I'm sure its rather easy but I have no idea as I'm very new to jQuery

**Solved - If someone wants to see it.. there we go:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/17/
**also this one...**
http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/18/

**Both answers work perfectly.. @jondavidjohn & @hunter Thank you guys... too bad I can't put Checkmark on both answers... but I will let hunter have it as his code is shorter.. :)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Make it so that once something is active, one will always be active:**

```
$("li:not(.active)").live("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

focuses only on `li`'s that aren't already active.

---

**To be able to deactivate:**

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/18/

Comment: nice, I like the `:not(.active)` +1

Comment: @hunter i kinda like that definition too but i cant seem to get it working.. http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/14/

Comment: @hunter Of course... :) Still it doesnt seem to remove class from '.active' from clicked '.active' li

Comment: oh, you want to be able to remove the class if you click it again?

Comment: @hunter Well jondavidjohn got it done so i just wanted to let you know.. you can Stop the presses. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Gotta say i feel a tad silly not figuring that out the first time you posted that code with the addClass...

Answer (score 5):

```
$( "li" ).click( function() {
    if( $(this).is('.active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass( "active" );
    }
    else {
        $( "li.active" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $(this).addClass( "active" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe even better: `$("li.active").removeClass( "active" );`

Comment: I like mine better because it's mine. +1

Comment: @jondavidjohn Well this is more or less what i already have. That code always make sure that there is .active in the clicked element and so, when you click li that is active it will remove .active first and then add .active again so i cant toggle it away.. which was also the point of this..

Comment: edited answer to define click events for only elements that are not `.active`

Comment: @user603568 Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, I assume you are trying to, 'on click', 1) add `.active` class to clicked elements and 2) remove the active class from elements that have not been clicked.  correct?

Comment: @jondavidjohn Yes, and thats what is being achieved right now.. but i also want the ability remove '.active' from clicked '.active' li ...i guess i wasnt being super clear about that..

Comment: @jondavidjohn Thats great... Thanks! 

I had a feeling if and else might do the trick but i dont know how to use them :)

Heres the 'demo' for anyone whos interested:
http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/17/